# non standard package name - will it cause trouble?

Tags: android

I have rather stupidly published a game on the android market with a package name of mick.game.tangletwister, whereas I should have called it com.rai.tangletwister (where rai is the name of my company)... it all seems to work fine - but could it cause some trouble in the future - should I change it? And if I do change it, will it cause problems for existing users that grab the updated version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be fine if you keep the existing package name. Nothing wrong with that. The TLD.company.appname format is just a convention. As long as you don't enter some special characters in your packagename (which you did not), it will work anyway.

But if you try to change it you will run into trouble. See [Things That Cannot Change](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you change the package, update notification will not work any more.  Moreover, when a user with the old package name installs the updated game, he/she will have both installed, because the update will *replace* the old version only if package/class are the same.

Depending on how many installs you have, you can, of course, remove the existing app from the Market - this should force-remove it from devices where it's installed.  Then you create another app (same metadata, naturally) and use a correct package name.

Answer (score 1):

1) Change the package name

2) Create a **new** app in the android market with that new package name

3) Update the old app, and add a pop-up saying that users should install a new version. Possible with a link to the new app

4) After some months, you should remove the old app.

Like user287351 said, it is possible to keep using the current package name, but i would prefer to have it listed under the correct package name

Comment: Presumably 99% of users would never even know that it had an unconventional name (would they?).

Comment: true indeed, but still I would recommend using "your" packagename.